# How to get @babel/register to transpile ESM imports?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, es6-modules

I am using the following to transpile TypeScript files at runtime.

```js
import babelRegister from "@babel/register"

babelRegister({
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
  extensions: [".tsx"],
  cache: false,
})
```

Everything worked fine until I tried migrating codebase from CommonJS to ESM.

According to Sindre Sorhus, one has to replace `require` with `import` and add `.js` when no extension was specified (`./src/routers/Static` refers to `./src/routers/Static.tsx`).

I replaced following

```js
const StaticRouter = require("./src/routers/Static").default
```

with

```js
import StaticRouter from "./src/routers/Static.js"
```

Now, following error is thrown.

```sh
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/src/routers/Static' imported from /Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/server.js
```

How can I circumvent error?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Stuck with this same issue. Did you ever solve?

Comment: @MichaelSherrisCaley Unfortunately I didn’t. Please let us know if ever you do.

Comment: I found a github open issue where they basically said that supported hadn't been added yet. So I went for a different approach and ran my stuff through webpack at build

Comment: I'm working on support for it. Note that it's still unofficial and may not work, but if you really need it here you go: https://github.com/mkg20001/babel/releases/tag/esm-loader-dev and here's how to use it: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/15456